# Merge [korma] and [sqlkorma] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

The [korma](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/korma/info) and [sqlkorma](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlkorma/info) tags are both about the [same library](http://sqlkorma.com/). I think korma should be the main tag, and sqlkorma an alias. Korma has 3x the number of questions, and is the official name of the project.